# Android app deletes file upon full exit (exit from task manager)

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream

I have a data store class that tried to adapt from an iOS Project. It works well for iOS, and it almost works for my android project, however, when exiting the android app from task manager, the file does not get restored on next run.

The intent of the class is if there is no file when saving the object, the class will create the file and save it. If there is a file, the class will open that file which contains an array, append the object to that array, and save it.

Is there something that I am missing to persist the file onto the device?

This is how I call the class to save the file

```
ObjectStore.defaultStore().saveObject(getApplicationContext(), anObject);
```

Here is my ObjectStore class

```
public class ObjectStore {

ArrayList<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();
static ObjectStore defaultStore = null;
Context context = null;

public static ObjectStore defaultStore(){
    if(defaultStore == null){
        defaultStore = new ObjectStore();
    }
    return defaultStore;
}

public Object ObjectStore(){
    if(defaultStore != null){
        return defaultStore;
    }
    return this;
}

public ArrayList<Object> objectList(){
    return objectList;
}

public Object saveObject(Context c, Object object){
    context = c;
    objectList.add(object);
    saveFile(context);
    return object; 
}

public void clearAll(){
    objectList.clear();
    saveFile(context);
}

public boolean doesFileExist(Context c){
    context = c;
    File file = c.getFileStreamPath("objectList.file");
    if(file.exists()){
        return true;
    }else{      
        return createFile(context);
    }
}

public boolean createFile(Context c){
    context = c;
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("objectList"+".file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(objectList);
        oos.close();
        return true;
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("TAG", "Error creating file: " + e);
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean saveFile(Context c){
    Log.d("TAG", "Trying to save file");
    context = c;
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("objectList.file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(objectList);
        oos.close();
        Log.d("TAG", "File Saved");
        return true;
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("TAG", "Error saving file: " + e);
        return false;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayList<Object> loadFile(Context c) throws Exception{
    Log.d("TAG", "Trying to load file");
    context = c;
    if(doesFileExist(context)){
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput("objectList.file");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            objectList = (ArrayList<Object>) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            Log.d("TAG", "File Loaded");
            return objectList;
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("TAG", "Error loading file: " + e);
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: When writing the file you are saving it as objectList.file... When opening the file you are opening objectList.data. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, that was mistake while posting, good eye though. I only wish that was the problem :-)

Comment: Do you ever get passed the `doesFileExist(context)` check?

Comment: I guess a better question would be at what point does your code break? The saving of the file or the reading of the file - then where specifically?

Comment: @MJesse : How do you define "exit from Task Manager"? Do you mean using "Force Stop" from Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications? If so, then the behaviour of using "Force Stop" is unpredictable as it quite literally just unloads a running app from memory without letting it go through its normal life-cycle methods such as `onPause()`, `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`.

Comment: This is how I exit, probably most graceful of options. Long press home > tap Task Manager > inside Active Applications I tap Exit

Comment: It seems that loadFile(Context c) is not getting called

Comment: @MJesse : OK, you've lost me. What is "Task Manager"? I have a phone running Android v2.2 and a tablet running v4.2 and neither give me anything called "Task Manager" if I long-press the Home button.

Comment: @Squonk, please see photo updated in answer

Comment: @Jeremy, loadFile was never called because there was nothing in that class that called it. You led me to realize that. Thank you. Please post in answer form so that I may accept.

Comment: @MJesse : Hmm, I don't see anything like that on my devices, I'm guessing it's specific to that manufacturer and/or device, Android version etc. I wonder if it's effectively a short way to get to  "Manage Applications". If that's the case "Exit" may well be the same as a "Force Stop".

Comment: @Squonk, this is a Samsung SPH-D700. I've heard a lot of manufacturers add their own junk to their devices. I also hear this drives developers nuts.

Comment: @MJesse : All manufacturers add their own junk to devices. If the Task Manager really is just a shortcut to allow you to "Force Stop" your app then basically you just need to make sure you're saving anything you need to persist in a relevant place in your code. As I said, a "Force Stop" will kill an app instantly - Android isn't like iOS and killing apps is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loadFile() is never being called!  There is nothing in there calling it! ;)